# participle clauses/absolute phrases

Tags: participles, absolute-constructions

> Being tired, I got some rest at home.
> Tired, I got some rest at home.
> Rich, he wasn't happy.

Why are the sentences above correct, but these aren't?

> Sick, he couldn't attend the meeting.
> Old, he couldn't find a job.

Comment: Who says they are 'correct'? I don't find the second and third very natural. 3 would be better as _Although rich, he wasn't happy._

Comment: @KateBunting I don't find 2 and 3 natural either. In fact, on first reading, I thought 3 was describing an unhappy man called Richard. I can't see any difference in validity between 2,3,4 and 5; I want to put "Being" in front of all of them except 3 where, as you say, "Although" would be better.

Comment: I remembered the hymn _Rock of Ages_ which contains the lines _Naked, [I] come to Thee for dress, Helpless, look to Thee for grace_ - but that is 18th century poetic language. A writer of fiction might say something like _Exhausted, he staggered up the path_.

Comment: "Being tired" is a non-finite clause functioning as a supplement. I take the others (though stylistically unnatural) to be predicative adjuncts: predicative because they relate to a predicand (i.e. the subjects "I" and "he"), and adjuncts because they are optional elements in clause structure.

Comment: They are all correct, and all somewhat unnatural.